# Searching the same values in an array

Tags: c#, algorithm

If I am not mistaken, this method has a complexity \$O(N^2)\$:

```
int[] exampleArray = { 4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 55, 55, 2, 5, 6, 90, 8, 8, 8, 10, 70 };
int k = GetMaximumCycle(exampleArray);

public static int GetMaximumCycle(int[] anArray)
{
   int length = anArray.Length;
   int result = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
      {
          if (anArray[i] == anArray[j])
          {
             if (!(result > Math.Abs(i - j)))                            
                 result = Math.Abs(i - j);
          }                    
      }                
   }
   return result;
}
```

I compare values and gets the maximum difference between items of array.
The `result` variable is 10.

And if an input array is very large, this code works slowly. Is it possible to simplify the `for` loops or remove the second `for` loop to have a complexity of \$O(N)\$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<int, int>` of positions of the first occurrence of each element value.
Next, iterating over all elements of the input array, you do:

- If the `positions[value]` is empty, store the current index `i` in it: `positions[value] = i`.
- Else, calculate the distance (or *cycle length*).
- If this distance is greater than maximum, save it as a new maximum.

This algorithm has time complexity \$O(n)\$.

The code:

```
public static class CycleSearch
{
    public static int GetMaximumCycle(int[] array)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> positions = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int value = array[i];
            int position;
            if (!positions.TryGetValue(value, out position))
            {
                positions[value] = i;
            }
            else
            {
                int cycleLength = i - position;
                if (cycleLength > result)
                {
                    result = cycleLength;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] exampleArray = { 4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 55, 55, 2, 5, 6, 90, 8, 8, 8, 10, 70 };
Console.WriteLine(CycleSearch.GetMaximumCycle(exampleArray));
```

Output:

> 10

Comment: You don't need to create an entire array that covers the full range of values for this, you could use a `Dictionary` (a.k.a. hash map)

Comment: thanks, man! You are really smart and wise guy! Thanks a lot!:)

Answer (score 2):

There is no real reason why your method should be restricted to `array` and `int`. You can make it easily generic (the below code is based on @Dmitry`s answer):

```
    public static class CycleSearch
    {
        public static int GetMaximumCycle<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
        {
            var positions = new Dictionary<T, int>();

            int result = 0;
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var value in sequence)
            {
                int position;
                if (!positions.TryGetValue(value, out position))
                {
                    positions[value] = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    int cycleLength = index - position;
                    if (cycleLength > result)
                    {
                        result = cycleLength;
                    }
                }
                index += 1;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

You are correct, it is \$O(n^2)\$.

I seriously doubt it is possible to reduce time complexity to \$O(n)\$, however there is a solution with \$O(n\log n)\$ time and \$O(n)\$ space complexity: sort the set of `(value, index)` pairs, and obtain the result in a single linear pass.

Comment: The result returned are the difference of the *indexes*. Sorting the array would swap the indexes.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely I am afraid you didn't pay attention. I suggested to sort the pairs, so each element keeps its original index along.

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, it would work. But still, a O(n) time solution *is* possible.